# Function to clear a cell based on clicking on a URL in a Google Spreadsheet to reopen a form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to create a function that will clear a cell when a URL on the active row is clicked? I need to clear the cell on the active row in column AG, or [32], whenever the response link on that cell is activated to be opened to go back to the form.
[image: Sampe of url links in spreadsheet below]

I have the code that creates the date value in the column I need cleared. The code is to disburse emails automatically (on a trigger) when an email is submitted. However, when a response needs to be added to the form, the 'Response Link' needs to be activated so the user can be taken back to the form to fill in response data. I want the emails to go out again when the form is updated. But because I added a date there to stop emails from going out over and over, updated emails cannot send. Once the form is resubmitted, it will put a date back into the cell.

```
function disburseEmails(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var allRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var allData = allRange.getValues();

  allData.shift();

  allData.forEach(function(row,i) {

if(row[32] === '') {

  // get data
  var dateSubmitted = row[0];
  var dateEdited = row[1];
  var studentID = row[2];
  var studentName = row[3];  
  var responseLink= row[4];
  var submitRespond = row[5];
  var senderName = row[6];
  var senderEmail = row[7];
  var senderPhone = row[8];
  var senderExt = row[9];
  var senderRole = row[10];
  var senderReason = row[11];
  var senderAdditional = row[12];
  var householdName = row[13];
  var householdAddress = row[14];
  var householdPhone = row[15]
  var studentGrade = row[16];
  var studentSchool = row[17];
  var anySiblings = row[18];
  var sibling1Name = row[19];
  var sibling1Grade = row[20];
  var sibling1School = row[21];
  var sibling2Name = row[22];
  var sibling2Grade = row[23];
  var sibling2School = row[24];
  var additionalSiblings= row[25];
  var numberHomeVisit = row[26];
  var responseContactName = row[27];
  var responseContactRelationship = row[28];
  var responseOutcome= row[29];
  var responseAdditional = row[30];
  var email = row[31];
  var confirmSenderEmail = row[32];

  // send an email to the sender for each row
  sendEmail(dateSubmitted, email, dateEdited, studentID, studentName, responseLink, submitRespond, senderName, senderEmail, senderPhone, senderExt, senderRole, senderReason, senderAdditional, householdName, householdAddress, householdPhone, studentGrade, studentSchool, anySiblings, sibling1Name, sibling1Grade, sibling1School, sibling2Name, sibling2Grade, sibling2School, additionalSiblings, numberHomeVisit, responseContactName, responseContactRelationship, responseOutcome, responseAdditional);

  // add date to confirm the sender email went out
  var d = new Date();
  sheet.getRange(i + 2, 33).setValue(d);


   }    
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hey @Karen, would you mind providing what you have tried in order to solve your question? Moreover, what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you just want to clear a specific cell when a link is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I just want to clear a specific cell when a link is clicked. I'm stumped to try and even write anything because I get tripped up trying to understand how the code knows where it (what row) is when the link is clicked. I pulled the code above from a course I'm taking online but I honestly don't know all that I'm doing. Some, but not all. I'm trying to learn. In the last line of the code, I can see that a date value is being added to the row created when the form is submitted. That prevents an email being sent out each time the sendEmail is executed.

Comment: The purpose of this form is to provide a means for school personnel to request our school security officer (RSO) to make home visit to students when necessary. On submit, the form fills out the spreadsheet and emails the RSO and person submitting. I created code to created a URL in the spreadsheet so the RSO can go back to the form after he has done the home visit and report the outcome. But because the code creates the date in a cell so an email won't be sent on every row in the spreadsheet again, it won't send an email again.

Comment: Which in essence is correct, but I need to remove that date when the RSO goes in a fills out the response information, then the code above will put it back in so further emails are not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's asssume you have the links the needed in the `F` column:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if(range.getColumn() == 6) {
    sheet.getRange("RANGE_OF_THE_CLEARED_CELL").clear();
  }
}
```

The above snippet uses an `onSelectionChange(e)` trigger which will trigger whenever a cell is selected. In order to check that a cell from the `F` row is selected, a condition is set and based on that, the cell wanted is cleared.
The code makes use the `e` event object which contains information about which cell has been selected.

#### Note

This works for all the cells in the `F` column, so if you want to make it specific to a particular cell, you can just add another condition and/or a loop to reflect the data you want accordingly.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) ;
- [Apps Script Class Sheet - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this and sending a possible solution. I do need to make it specific to the cell that is on the row of the cell where I click the URL.  I'm guessing (truly guessing) that I would add this function to the code; and add the same row reference from the where I put a new date to the function: sheet.getRange(i + 2, 33).clear()?; call the function under the if statement BEFORE the sendEmail function so it can remove the date if it needs to?; and pass in the function like this:  onSelectionChange(i + 2, 33).  Am I close?  I wanted to run by you first, since this form is live.

Comment: The `onSelectionChange` is a trigger which uses the `e` event object. This event object, in your situation, will give you the data regarding which cell was selected. `range` is the method - the only range you have to add is in the `getRange()` method. Moreover, just like I have mentioned, when you click any cell in the `F` column, one cell will be cleared. If you want to make it specific to your particular use case, just add other loops/conditions needed. Cheers!